# Laptop's white/blank screen. Curable?

Tags: boot, laptop, lcd

So, i've got my precious, old Dell Vostro 1510, which recently started to show me completely white/blank screen in 4-5 seconds after i turn it on. At times, some thin vertical multicolored lines can also be seen along with it. No beeps. I can clearly hear that the system boots fine, there's just no picture output...

What i've done so far:

1. According to service manual, some malfunctions can be identified by reading the sequence of keyboard status lights (num/caps/srollLock). Not in my case - these lights are dead, or at least they show no automatic signals whatsoever. I can turn each of them on, but only manually.
2. Drained residual power several times (took off battery, held power button for 1-2 mins). Didn't help much..
3. Reseated memory sticks (there are 2 of them). Tried various configurations, like insert only first, then only second, then switch slots, etc. No use.
4. Connected an external monitor to check if the videocard could cause the trouble. Apparently videocard wasn't the problem, as the laptop worked just fine with the external monitor.
5. Taking the advantage of having my picture "back", i entered BIOS and reset its setting to defaults.
6. I then disassembled the display and reseated the display cable which connects the monitor with videocard. Visually the cable looked fine, I saw nothing unordinary about it, no jams or bends or any other signs of damage, so I just pulled it out and pluged it back in. Along the way i've also reseated display inverter connectors. Unfortunately that didn't help as well.

Well, i'm kind of out of options by now... The problem can be caused by either the defective display cable, inverter or LCD itself. Is there any way to narrow the list by means of some test that could be performed at home? Or perhaps i'm missing something. Anyway any help would matter, thanks!

### EDIT:

For those of you guys, who might suffer the similar issue and are looking for a **solution**: in my case the faulty part was the LCD, or to be more exact - the controller chip on it. I took the laptop to a technician. He had tons of spare parts for laptops, LCDs in particular. So, after he replaced my LCD with one of his own, everything started to work, i.e there was a picture output. Unfortunately he couldn't find an appropriate LCD model suitable for my laptop (HD was required), so eventually he just removed the faulty controller chip from my LCD and soldered a new one to it

Comment: Based on what you have written, I would still suspect the cable between the graphics array and the display itself. You may want to go over it really carefully to make sure there aren't any bends or any damage to the cable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to incorporate additional information. Consider taking the site [tour]. Thanks!

Comment: For those of you guys, who might suffer the similar issue and are looking for a solution: in my case the faulty part was the LCD, or to be more exact - the controller chip on it. I took the laptop to a technician. He had tons of spare parts for laptops, LCDs in particular. So, after he replaced my LCD with one of his own, everything started to work, i.e there was a picture output. Unfortunately he couldn't find an appropriate LCD model suitable for my laptop (HD was required), so eventually he just removed the faulty controller chip from my LCD and soldered a new one to it.

Comment: I would suggest that you write that up as a proper answer. See http://superuser.com/help/self-answer and http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer for some pointers.